# set directory to a path in a file

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I just want to set the directory to a path I have written in a file before.

Therefore I used :

```
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("path.txt"));
```

and in path.txt the path is given. But unfortunately this does not work out and I wonder why :P.
I think I got it all wrong with the `setCurrentDic`..

Comment: setCurrentDirectory accepts a path, not a file name. So your new File("path.txt") will only signify that the current working directory will be set as **your** current directory. Read the javadocs once again.

Answer (score 2):

`setCurrentDirectory` takes a file representing a directory as parameter. Not a text file where a path is written.

To do what you want, you have to read the file "path.txt", create a File object with the contents that you just read, and pass this file to setCurrentDirectory :

```
String pathWrittenInTextFile = readFileAsString(new File("path.txt"));
File theDirectory = new File(pathWrittenInTextFile);
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the contents of `path.txt`. Thea easiest way is through [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
String fileContents = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("path.txt"));
File dir = new File(fileContents);
```

You can also use `FileUtils.readFileToString(..)`

Comment: ah okay, I see...but IOUtils.toString(new File("path.txt")); throws the error, that toString is not applicable for the argument file

Answer (score 0):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

try {
    // Create a File object containing the canonical path of the
    // desired directory
    File f = new File(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());

    // Set the current directory
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```